# What is the best way to create a figure with distributions as insets in python?

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib

I created a graph in MATLAB (see figure below) such that around every data point there is a data distribution plotted (grey area plots). The way I did it in MATLAB was to create a set of axes for every distribution curve and then plot the curves without showing those axes at every point of the data curve. I also used a command 'linkaxes' to set figure limits for all the curves at once.

I must say that this is far from an elegant solution and I had many troubles with saving this figure in the correct aspect ratio settings. All in all I couldn't find any other useful option in MATLAB.

Is there a more elegant solution for such types of graphs in Python? I am not that much interested in how to do the areas highlighted, but how to place a set of curves(distributions) exactly at the positions of the main data curve points.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: You could use e.g. https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.fill_betweenx.html, although it wouldn't be a very pretty solution

Comment: Side question: couldn't you use a single axis with `hold on` in MATLAB?

Comment: The reason I couldn't use hold on is that the function I used in MATLAB to create filled curves works in a way that it fills area between a curve and an axis. This means that every distribution curve in the figure wold potentially like to fill all the area up to y-axis. So I had to create axes for every curve so the filling comes in right limits.